# What is the best way to wrap some text in an xml tag?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to use Regex in C# to match a section in an xml document and wrap that section inside of a tag.

For example, I have this section:

```
<intro>
    <p>this is the first section of content</p>
    <p> this is another</p>
</intro>
```

and I want it to look like this:

```
<intro>
   <bodyText>
      <p> this is asdf</p>
      <p> yada yada </p>
   </bodyText>
</intro>
```

any thoughts?

I was considering doing it using the XPath class in C# or just by reading in the document and using Regex. I just can't seem to figure it out either way.

here is the one try:

```
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath);
        string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();

        /* The regex stuff would go here */

        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath);
        writer.Write(content);
        writer.Close();
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Seems like you might want XSLT.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using 3.5 and I am using XSLT for some things, I might use it for this, I was just hoping to find a quick C# solution so that I can spend more time writing presentation code in XSLT rather than organizational code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend regular expressions for this task. Instead you can do it using LINQ to XML. For example, here is how you could wrap some tags inside a new tag:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("input.xml");
var section = doc.Root.Elements("p");
doc.Root.ReplaceAll(new XElement("bodyText", section));
Console.WriteLine(doc.ToString());
```

Result:

```
<intro>
  <bodyText>
    <p>this is the first section of content</p>
    <p> this is another</p>
  </bodyText>
</intro>
```

I assume that your actual document differs considerably from the example you posted so the code will need some adjustment to fit your requirements, but if you read the documentation for [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387063.aspx) you should be able to do what you want.

Comment: Though I agree with this approach, I don't think that code actually does what OP wanted.

Comment: @hemp: Yes, I'm not claiming that he can blindly copy & paste this code into his project and all his problems will be solved, but hopefully it's enough of a hint to get started.

Comment: I read through it again and tried it myself, I was wrong - your code does exactly what he asked. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the use of System.XML and XPath - I don't think XML is considered a regular language similar to HTML which causes issues when trying to parse it with Regular expressions.

Use something like

```
XMLDocument doc = new XMLDocument();
doc.Load("Path to your xml document");
```

Enjoy!